# How specific should a Support Vector Machine Model be?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, svm, prediction

The whole point of using an SVM is that the algorithm will be able to decide whether an input is true or false etc etc.

I am trying to use an SVM for predictive maintenance to predict how likely a system is to overheat.

For my example, the range is 0-102°C and if the temperature reaches 80°C or above it's classed as a failure.

My inputs are arrays of 30 doubles(the last 30 readings).

I am making some sample inputs to train the SVM and I was wondering if it is good practice to pass in very specific data to train it - eg passing in arrays 80°C, 81°C ... 102°C so that the model will automatically associate these values with failure. You could do an array of 30 x 79°C as well and set that to pass.

This seems like a complete way of doing it, although if you input arrays like that - would it not be the same as hardcoding a switch statement to trigger when the temperature reads 80->102°C.

Would it be a good idea to pass in these "hardcoded" style arrays or should I stick to more random inputs?

Comment: That's unclear and broad. Additionally: if your sample-readings are measured temperatures at some time t, passing those measured values and using SVMs does not make any sense from a ML-standpoint.

Comment: It is definitely possible, however. As the comment above says, this seems like an odd problem to use a classification algorithm for. Especially since you want the result, the likelihood, to be a float, I am assuming.

Comment: @sascha I would appreciate more of an answer to the question I was trying to ask rather than criticising my questioning skills, but cheers for the input on the second part.

Comment: @Alien13 yeah it might not be the best way for this specific problem, but I’d still quite like to know how close your model should be to a full hardcoded solution. If you had the resources to train the model over every possible set of inputs(assuming the problem is over some finite set of possibilities etc), would it be good practice to have a trained scenario for every case? This kind of defeats the purpose of using an SVM as it becomes more of a check than a prediction. How far should you take your model? Or is an SVM mainly supposed to be used for infinite scenario problems? Cheers.

Comment: If there is a finite set of possibilities I would really recommend using Naïve Bayes, as that method would fit this problem perfectly. However if you are forced to use an SVM, I would say that would be rather difficult. For starters the main idea with an SVM is to use it for classification, and the amount of scenarios does not really matter. The input is however seldom discrete, so I guess there usually are infinite scenarios. However, an SVM implemented normally would only give you a classification, unless you have 100 classes one for 1% another one for 2%, this wouldn't really solve problem.

Comment: The conclusion is that this could work, but it would not be considered "best practice". You can imagine your 30 dimensional vector space divided into 100 small sub spaces, and each datapoint, a 30x1 vector is a point in that vectorspace so that the probability is decided by which of the 100 subsets its in. However, having a 100 classes and not very clean or insufficient data, will lead to very bad, hard performing models.

Comment: @Alien13 perfect thanks a million that’s all I was wondering about. If you want to post that as an answer I’ll accept it.

Comment: Yeah sure, I guess that should have been an answer rather than a comment. It became longer than I thought haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a finite set of possibilities I would really recommend using Naïve Bayes, as that method would fit this problem perfectly. However if you are forced to use an SVM, I would say that would be rather difficult. For starters the main idea with an SVM is to use it for classification, and the amount of scenarios does not really matter. The input is however seldom discrete, so I guess there usually are infinite scenarios. However, an SVM implemented normally would only give you a classification, unless you have 100 classes one for 1% another one for 2%, this wouldn't really solve problem.

The conclusion is that this could work, but it would not be considered "best practice". You can imagine your 30 dimensional vector space divided into 100 small sub spaces, and each datapoint, a 30x1 vector is a point in that vectorspace so that the probability is decided by which of the 100 subsets its in. However, having a 100 classes and not very clean or insufficient data, will lead to very bad, hard performing models.

Cheers :)